# Multiple Ajax calls slow page down

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, camera

How can I reduce, that multiple ajax calls slow my page down? At the moment I have an ip camera stream on my (local) website. Now I have every second 8 ajax calls (5x read & 3x write). But the problem is, that every second when the ajax calls be executed, the stream get stuck some miliseconds. How can I do solve the problem?

Here is the `setInterval` function with the ajax calls:

```
var oneSec = setInterval(function(){
    var status = 0;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: 'getMoveUpButtonStatus.html',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            status = data.replace("<a>", "");
            status = status.replace("</a>", "");
        }
    });
    
    var isEnabled = 0;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: 'getStartStopStatus.html',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            isEnabled = data.replace("<a>", "");
            isEnabled = isEnabled.replace("</a>", "");
        }
    });
    
    var status = 0;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: 'getMoveDownButtonStatus.html',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            status = data.replace("<a>", "");
            status = status.replace("</a>", "");
        }
    });
    
    var status;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: 'getLifeBit.html',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            status = data.replace("<a>", "");
            status = status.replace("</a>", "");
        }
    });
    
    var status = 0;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: 'getStatus.html',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            status = data.replace("<a>", "");
            status = status.replace("</a>", "");
        }
    });
    
    
    var sdata = escape('"DB_VLD".Status.Lebensbit_BGD_1') + '=' + 0;
    $.post('setLifeBit.html', sdata, function(result){});
    
    var sdata = escape('"DB_VLD".Taste.BGD_1_Heben') + '=' + value;
    $.post('setMoveUp.html', sdata, function(result){});    

    var sdata = escape('"DB_VLD".Taste.BGD_1_Senken') + '=' + value;
    $.post('setMoveDown.html', sdata, function(result){});
}, 1000);
```

Here is a image of the `timing chart` from IE.

[image: time chart]

How can I improve the ajax calls? I build the ajax calls like this page explained: [SiemensPage](https://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/id/8567/siemens-s7-1200-web-server-tutorial--from-getting-started-to-html5-user-defined-pages)

Im using a `Lupus electronics` ip camera.

Comment: `async: false,` is the couse

Comment: better rethink this code

Comment: @madalinivascu thanks for you answer! the problem is, that the buttons control a SPS. And then I have to check if the bit is set or not.

Comment: strange you are calling html files ,those are static,adn what's a SPS

Comment: @madalinivascu here is a [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_logic_controller). Inside the html files is only a variable name, that I want to read, as example the `getStatus.html`: `<!-- AWP_In_Variable Name='"DB_VLD".Status.Frg_BGD_1' --><a>:="DB_VLD".Status.Frg_BGD_1:</a>`. And normally I dont write websites... so its a challange for me.

Comment: @madalinivascu but I think your right with `async: false`. I tested it, and it looks good.

Comment: you are programming a PLC with javascipt that is something new :)

Comment: @madalinivascu I fixed the problem now. Thanks for your help! :)